# Preview image upload with React Functions

Tags: reactjs

hello im trying to make a image upload and preview but i can only find react tutorials on how to do this using class components

```
import React from 'react';


const AddNew = () => {
    const fileHandler = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.files[0])
    }
    const alt = (event) => {
        return(event.target.files[0].name)
    }
    const preview = (event) => {
        return (
            URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
        )
    }
    return (
        <div className="addNew">
            <img src={preview} alt={alt}/>
            <input type="file" onChange={fileHandler} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddNew
```

how do i preview it using this syntax?

i get an error for invalid values for props 'src' and 'alt'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use state to let React know when to re-render. You can use useState hook to save your component state and file information, and when it changes, React knows it's the time to render.

```js
const AddNew = ({}) => {
    const [file, setFile] = React.useState(null)
    
    const fileHandler = (e) => {
        setFile(e.target.files[0])
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={file? URL.createObjectURL(file) : null} alt={file? file.name : null}/>
            <input type="file" onChange={fileHandler} />
        </div>
    )
}



ReactDOM.render(<AddNew />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a bit of state to provide an initial value for `src` and `alt` and hold the updated values.

```
const initialState = { alt: "", src: "" };

const AddNew = () => {
  const [{ alt, src }, setPreview] = useState(initialState);

  const fileHandler = event => {
    const { files } = event.target;
    setPreview(
      files.length
        ? {
            src: URL.createObjectURL(files[0]),
            alt: files[0].name
          }
        : initialState
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="addNew">
      <img className="preview" src={src} alt={alt} />
      <input accept="image/*" type="file" onChange={fileHandler} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit image preview]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `FileReader` to convert the image to base64 string. Assuming you are doing a single file upload, just maintain a state for eg: `file` and set the state after the `filereader` `onload` listener is done reading image.

Working copy of your code is here:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const AddNew = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const fileHandler = event => {
    console.log(event.target.files[0]);
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      setFile(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="addNew">
      <img src={file} alt={""} />
      <input type="file" onChange={fileHandler} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddNew;
```